# Spy on a Javascript function with Capybara-Webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Capybara-Webkit and Cucumber on a Rails project, and I was wondering if it's possible to spy on a global Javascript function on the Cucumber step definitions, so I can assert the Javascript function is called or not when a event is triggered.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might not feel like an answer but I might suggest that you shouldn't be spying on javascript in an acceptance test - ideally an acceptance test is treating the system as a black box so you are only checking behaviour that the real user would observe ....

my sense is that if you really want to spy then that should be done in a jasmine test and not in a cucumber/capybara acceptance test ...

Comment: Thank you @sam-joseph, you're right. Since I'm not asserting something that's visible to the user, a unit test with Jasmine would be better.